# Tkinter gives me a second window

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing code for a tkinter gui using a class, however I notice that when I run there is a second window besides the main one I made. I've tried a number of things but they either break the code or the window is black. See code below.

```
import tkinter as gui

class loginWindow(gui.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(loginWindow, self).__init__()
        self.logUI()


def logUI(self):
    self.mainWindow = gui.Tk()
    self.mainWindow.title("GLSC IT Inventory")
    self.mainWindow.minsize(400, 150)
    self.mainWindow.maxsize(400, 150)
    self.mainWindow.geometry("400x150")

    self.greet_label = gui.Label(self.mainWindow, text="Welcome!!!")
    self.greet_label.place(x=180, y=5)

    self.uname_label = gui.Label(self.mainWindow, text="Username:")
    self.uname_label.place(x=10, y=24)

    self.uname_input = gui.StringVar()
    self.uname_field = gui.Entry(self.mainWindow, bd=4, textvariable=self.uname_input)
    self.uname_field.place(x=80, y=25, width=160)

    self.pwd_label = gui.Label(self.mainWindow, text="Password:")
    self.pwd_label.place(x=10, y=54)

    self.pwd_input = gui.StringVar()
    self.pwd_field = gui.Entry(self.mainWindow, bd=4, textvariable=self.pwd_input, show="\u2022")
    self.pwd_field.place(x=80, y=55, width=160)

    self.login_button = gui.Button(self.mainWindow, text="Login", command=None)
    self.login_button.place(x=180, y=95)
```

my_app = loginWindow()
my_app.mainloop()

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code. `logUI` seems to be incorrectly indented, and the last couple of lines of the code has the wrong formatting.

Comment: Sorry, that's due to some issues I had pasting the code here, it is correct in my IDE.

Comment: We can only see the code that you post.

Comment: I know, what I am saying is that I made a mistake while posting the code so it is not aligned correctly. Never the less @acw1668 has answered the question so its all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create instance of `loginWindow()`, an instance of `Tk()` is required but there is none, so it will be created implicitly for you.

Then another instance of `Tk()` is created inside `logUI()`.  So there are two instances of `Tk()`.

One way to fix it is `loginWindow` not inherited from `Frame`:

```py
class loginWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logUI()

    def logUI(self):
        ...

    # add for calling tkinter.mainloop()
    def mainloop(self):
        self.mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, also the explanation is much appreciated, I'll know how to avoid in future.